# Minimal value of a diophantine expression

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

Given the expression $$x^a - y^b>0$$ what is the minimum positive value it can have given $x>y > 1$ and $a,b>1$. For example, if I have $4^a - 3^b$ I would conjecture that the smallest value would be for $4^2 - 3^2 = 7$. Another close solution would be $4^4 - 3^5 = 13$. But how would I formally prove it, and if there is a smaller value how would I find the smallest one?

Comment: $3^2-2^3=1$ *is* the minimum. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: If I have answered your question fully please accept my answer to complete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $4^a-3^b$, by Mihăilescu's theorem (in reference to solutions of the equation $x^a - y^b = 1$)
we know that $8,9$ are the only consecutive powers and so $4^a-3^b > 1$. Working $\mod 2,3$ it is clear that $4^a-3^b \neq 2,3,4,6$. Rechecking $\mod 3$ we have for the equation $4^a-3^b = 5$ that $1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ meaning that $5$ is not a solution either and $7 = 4^a - 3^b$ is the minimal solution.

Comment: 5 could still be a possible solution right?

Comment: Still editing/thinking.

Comment: Catalan's conjecture is indeed true. We also call it Mihăilescu's theorem now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: @player3236, wow very cool, the number theory book I have in my hands is by Melvyn Nathanson from 2000.

Comment: Besides, the case $4^a - 3^b \ne 1$ has elementary proofs. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888687/let-m-n-in-mathbbz-and-p-be-an-odd-prime-number-show-that-n-1-if-2/3888708#3888708 for two of them. +1 for the remaining cases $2, ... ,6$.

Comment: If you know of where we can read that proof I'd like to know! It is difficult for me to find certain results...

Comment: https://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/preda/mihailescu-papers/catber.pdf

Comment: Is there an efficient and general method to find the minimum, or some kind of bounds we can put on it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The study of diophantine equations can require a lot of deep mathematics. Consider that there isn't really any good reason why $7$ is the minimal solution to this equation other than that we found one and there couldn't be a smaller one. There is no good reason why there would be some powerful method in general to solve such equations. Much of the time it takes plenty of work!